# Google application marketplace API does not work

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, http-status-code-503

We use *Google API* https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/appId endpoint and it works some time, but for now it returns `503 response` with error message

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"backendError","message":"Temporary error. Please try later."}],"code":503,"message":"Temporary error. Please try later."}}
```

Could anyone suggest what it can be and how to fix this problem?